# Nullification of non-kosher utensils or dishes

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, bitul-batel-null, keilim

If an unidentifiable non kosher utensil or vessel gets mixed up with kosher vessels, if the majority of vessels are kosher, it is nullified. [1] If someone makes this mistake a million times, are all the utensils or vessels still kosher?

[1]http://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=4622

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a dry *issur* (forbidden thing)  that was already *Batel berov* (nulified) can be considered *heter* (completely permitted like the majority) to nullify more *issur* is a debate. Shach says yes Pri Chodosh ( Chavos daas and latter poskim all agree with Pri chodosh) says no. Pri Megadim Yore dea99,21

> עש"ך...ביבש  במין במינו  כל שנפל לרוב היתר ונתבטל אין חוזר וניעור ואדרבה אפשר שגם האיסור מצטרף להעלות'. והפר"ח אות כ"א התיר אפילו בלח במינו כל שנודע אין חוזר וניעור ומיהו אם נתרבה ורוב באיסור אסור אף במינו